# Visual studio 2012 deploy to single assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment

How can i configure visual studio 2012 to publish website and merge IL to one assembly.
in visual studio 2010 we had deployment projects , in vs 2012 they are not supported...

Edit: I have a web-site project and not web application.

Comment: Consider upgrading to a web application project.

Comment: Is there another option avaliable maybe ? The project is very large , and I think it will take too much time to update it , since conversion process isn't so simple... As far as I know for each runat=server vs 2012 will try to add property to designer file , and in this proj there are a lot of UI (td , div , ul ) tags with runat=server , so it can be a hell to convert this...

Comment: You sound like you're the one who will be adding the fields to the .designer.cs file. Make a copy, run the "Convert to Web Application" command on the copy, go to lunch.

Comment: No John , I sound like the one who will need to remove them :-). I've performed conversions for smaller projects, and it wasn't just click and goto lunch. Anyway thanks for ur suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the WebSite project and start "Publish Web Site".  That brings up a dialog to start/configure the publish process.  The first step of the wizard lets you select an existing publish profile or create a new one.  The second step let you select the publish method.  The really interesting step is the third one, the "Settings" step.  It has an expandable section named "File Publish Options".  Expanding it reveals three options where the second one ("Precompile during publishing") has a clickable link that brings you to another dialog that allows you to do advanced precompile settings.  The second section on this dialog deals with merge options.